# Kotlin Associate With New Items At End of List

Tags: java, list, sorting, kotlin

I am trying to use `associate` in kotlin to order one list according to another list. Here is my code:

```kotlin
    val a = listOf("G", "F", "E", "D", "C", "B", "A")
    val b = listOf("A", "G", "C")
    val order = b.withIndex().associate { it.value to it.index }
    println(a.sortedBy { order[it] })
```

this is outputting: `[F, E, D, B, A, G, C]`
Notice how this code is placing the items that are not part of `b` at the beginning of the list. Is there a simple way to instead put the new items **at the end of the list.** So the output would be like this instead: `[A, G, C, F, E, D, B]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `order[it]` doesn't find the value in the dictionary, it returns `null`, which is sorted as less than any integers. You can use the alternative `?:` operator to provide a value of your choice. If you want it to appear at the end, you can use `Int.MAX_VALUE` to return the largest possible integer.

```
>>> println(a.sortedBy { order[it] ?: Int.MAX_VALUE })
[A, G, C, F, E, D, B]
```